# How to fix the SMTP errors when sending a mail with phpmailer

Tags: php, html

I know this question was asked many times, but I still can't find a solution to this problem.

I am trying to use PHP Mailer to send mail from a local MAMP server.

I have checked all the things that the wiki/troubleshooting of PHP Mailer asks and everything works, so I don't know how to solve this.

Here is the code:

```
try {
        $mail = new PHPmailer(true);
        $mail->SetLanguage('fr');
        $mail->IsSMTP();
        $mail->IsHTML(true);
        $mail->SMTPDebug=1;
        $mail->SMTPAuth=true;
        $mail->SMTPSecure='ssl';
        $mail->Host= 'smtp-mail.outlook.com';
        $mail->Port='587';
        $mail->Username='******@hotmail.fr';
        $mail->Password='******';
        $mail->From='******@hotmail.fr';
        $mail->AddAddress('******@hotmail.fr');
        $mail->CharSet="utf-8";
        $mail->Subject='Newsletter';
        $mail->Body=$msg;
        $mail->Send();
    }
    catch (Exception $e) {
        echo $e->errorMessage();
    }
```

And the only response that I got as an error message is:

> 2019-07-08 12:38:55 SMTP ERROR: Failed to connect to server: (0) Échec
>   de la connexion SMTP.
>   https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting Échec de
>   la connexion SMTP.
>   https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting

Can someone help?

Comment: Have you gone through the troubleshooting steps provided in the github link that is recommended? https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting#check-its-there-at-all

Comment: I think that the port has to be a number, not a string, and you might play around with the SMTPSecure and Port settings.   either tls / 587 or ssl / 465.  You might even want to consider mailtrap.io or something similar to see if it something to do with you outlook account.  Here is another SO Post that might have something useful:   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34012142/mamp-php-mailer-not-working

Comment: Hello Felix, yes i have done all the steps like i said in the topic.
sscotti, i search with my mail with port and it is 587, I try to write the port as a number in the code, doesn't work too.

Comment: Ok its done thanks to sscotti, i change just the protocol ssl into tbs with the same port and its works. Thank you !!